# Form_for doesn't work with JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have problems getting a form to work when I use JavaScript with it.
Without the remote option set to true all works fine but as soon as I
set it, change the controller and create the needed JS files it produces an

`POST .. 500 Internal Server Error`

when clicking on the submit button.

Furthermore the reply-preview shows me a Rails Error Page saying

`NoMethodError in Vocabs#create` and `undefined method > for nil:NilClass`

in a related partial (which works fine before using JS)

The form (vocabs/_new_form.html.erb) looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @vocab, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', f: f %> 
  <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The vocab_controller's create action like this:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @vocab = current_user.vocabs.build(vocab_params) 
    @vocabs = @user.vocabs.paginate(page: params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
            if @vocab.save
                flash.now[:success] = "Vocab created!"
                  redirect_to root_url

            else 
                flash.now[:error] = "Vocab not saved!"              
                render 'new'                
            end
        }
        format.js
    end 
end
```

The create.js.erb like this:

```
$('#new_vocab').remove();
```

Of course I want to do more than just to remove the form but as I didn't even manage to do that I wanted to keep it simple.

---

_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %> 

<div class="field"> 
<%= f.label :nl_word, @user.native_language %>
<%= f.text_field :nl_word %>

<%= f.label :fl_word, @user.foreign_language %>
<%= f.text_field :fl_word %>

<%= f.label :tag, "Your Tag" %>
<%= f.text_field :tag%>

<%= f.label :importance, "Importance" %>
<%= f.select(:importance, options_for_select(
                StaticData::IMPORTANCE_SEED, :selected => f.object.importance)) %>
</div>
```

I hope I could explain myself good enough to get some help here. I tried for hours to find the solution to the problem myself and was looking for similar questions here without finding any and without getting anywhere.

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` is exactly what it sounds like, something went wrong on your server, and it's very clear from the error message what it was.

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: You'll need to include your code

Comment: Sorry, code is included now. I accidently submitted the question.

Comment: Please include your `_fields` partial as well. Apparently that's where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friend I found out that the main problem was that I didn't provide any validation for the vocab object i wanted to create in the form (_new_form.html.erb), when processing it with JS.

So I changed the vocab_controller.rb to

```
def create
@user = current_user
@vocab = current_user.vocabs.build(vocab_params) 
@vocabs = @user.vocabs.paginate(page: params[:page])

respond_to do |format|

    if @vocab.save
        flash.now[:success] = "Vocab created!"

        format.html do
            redirect_to root_url
        end

        format.js 

    else 
        flash.now[:error] = "Vocab not saved!"

        format.html do
            render 'new'
        end

        format.js 
    end
end 
end
```

That does the trick, and my form works with JS now.